# Flask - Elastic Beanstalk Deploy - requirements.txt non-zero exit status

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm able to run this web app locally that uses AWS for its db, but every deploy I end up getting the following error. I'm using Python 3 (3.4 per AWS requirements):

```
  2017-05-10 04:18:47,980 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)   CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

Here's what my requirements.txt looks like, which includes a lot of packages that are dependent upon others:

> ```
> appdirs==1.4.3
> asn1crypto==0.22.0
> cffi==1.10.0
> click==6.7
> cryptography==1.8.1
> enum34==1.1.6
> Flask==0.12.1
> Flask-GoogleMaps==0.2.4
> Flask-MySQL==1.4.0
> idna==2.5
> image==1.5.5
> ipaddress==1.0.18
> itsdangerous==0.24
> Jinja2==2.9.6
> MarkupSafe==1.0
> olefile==0.44
> packaging==16.8
> Pillow==4.1.1
> pycparser==2.17
> PyMySQL==0.7.11
> pyOpenSSL==17.0.0
> pyparsing==2.2.0
> six==1.10.0
> Werkzeug==0.12.1
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow solved this by ensuring I had `virtualenv -p python3 VENV` and then adding an .ebextensions folder with a .config file containing:

```
packages:
    yum:
        libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
```

As was suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35168068/7982502