# How can I use my firebase credentials in a Flask application that I want to deploy in a AWS elastic beanstalk?

Tags: flask, firebase-authentication, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, firebase-admin

Inside my **.zip** source boudle I have:

- templates/
- application.py
- serviceKey.json
- requirements.txt

It runs locally in my machine with the following code, but when I deploy it in AWS elastic beanstalk it doesn't work.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, db

application = app = Flask(__name__)

cred = credentials.Certificate('./serviceKey.json') 
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {"databaseURL": "<URL_to_my_firebasedb>"})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work". Do you get any errors or some other logs?

Comment: Hi @HiranyaJayathilaka.  I get an environment health status of **"Degraded"** and in causes it says: "Application deployment failed at 2020-05-12T05:03:20Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed".


Also if I go to the URL of the application, the page shows **"Index of/"**

Comment: Looks like a deployment problem at the AWS end. The code looks fine, and I'd expect it to work in any environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my code was right, my problem had something to do with an **invalid requirements.txt** error that says: `requirements.txt returned non-zero exit status 1.`

My solution of my problem was to create other **.zip** source boundle that does not include the requirements.txt but the `venv` foler that I had in my local computer.

So the new **.zip** source boudle looks like this:

- templates/
- venv/
- application.py
- serviceKey.json

I get it from this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43967554/13450998